# Can I automatically add a new host to known_hosts?

Tags: linux, ssh, known-hosts

Here's my situation: I'm setting up a test harness that will, from a central client, launch a number of virtual machine instances and then execute commands on them via `ssh`.  The virtual machines will have previously unused hostnames and IP addresses, so they won't be in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on the central client.

The problem I'm  having is that the first `ssh` command run against a new virtual instance always comes up with an interactive prompt:

```
The authenticity of host '[hostname] ([IP address])' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is [key fingerprint].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Is there a way that I can bypass this and get the new host to be already known to the client machine, maybe by using a public key that's already baked into the virtual machine image ?  I'd really like to avoid having to use Expect or whatever to answer the interactive prompt if I can.

Comment: For a test environment which is self-contained and physically secure, automated key acceptance may work just fine. But automatically accepting public keys in a production environment or across an untrusted network (such as the Internet) completely bypasses any protection against man-in-the-middle attacks that SSH would otherwise afford. The *only* valid way to make sure you're secure against MITM attacks is to verify the host's public key through some out-of-band trusted channel. There is no secure way to automate it without setting up a moderately complicated key signing infrastructure.

Comment: Old questions, still useful. I found a correct and safe answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906302/add-public-key-to-known-hosts-file/34908270#34908270 .TL;DR: get the public key by any out-of-band means (the virtual infrastructure will provide this), generate a line in the client's `known_hosts`. You might consider skipping the "rehash" step.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Set the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option to `no`, either in the config file or via `-o` :

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@hostname.com`

Comment: This leaves you open to man in the middle attacks, probably not a good idea.

Comment: @JasperWallace, while this is usually good advice, the specific use case (deploying test VMs and sending commands to them) should be safe enough.

Comment: This gives a `Warning: Permanently added 'hostname,1.2.3.4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.` To avoid the warning, and to avoid the entry being added to any known_hosts file, I do: `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null username@hostname.com`

Comment: Note that this must make the connection, so if you need to connect to a port, use `-p [port]`, and if you're automating the process and need to immediate disconnect, send any command you're allowed to execute on the target machine. eg `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com -p 2020 'echo hello'`

Comment: Downvoting as this does not answer the question and opens to serious security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I also downvoted this. I want to securely connect, not defeat my own ssh.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo: If you were worried about security then you wouldn't have anything at all to do with this question. You'd have the correct host key in front of you, gathered from the console of the system you wanted to connect to, and you would manually verify it upon first connecting. You certainly wouldn't do anything "automatically".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, just add a disclaimer about the security. This answer is perfectly acceptable with knowledge of impact to security. Many environments, like behind corp firewalls, make the security issue not as dramatic.

Comment: Deactivating security features to supress 'irritating' warnings is a very bad practise!

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Comment: This answer should mention the risk of MiTM.

Comment: although this answer is insecure it explicitly answers the question (which even includes the word "bypass") so it seems to me the most correct answer.  If this was done in a secure testing network which seems to be the aim of the question this wouldn't be a problem.  I've edited it to make the risks more clear.  Hopefully that makes it okay.

Comment: If really needed, use `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` instead `=no` ([see my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/977776/157527)). Otherwise @JasperWallace [is right](https://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts/977776#comment622492_132973): you're always subject to a man-in-the-middle attack on each connection to the server.

Comment: This is the right way to do it, sometimes security just gets in the way, +1.

Answer (score 287):

IMO, the best way to do this is the following:

```
ssh-keygen -R [hostname]
ssh-keygen -R [ip_address]
ssh-keygen -R [hostname],[ip_address]
ssh-keyscan -H [hostname],[ip_address] >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H [ip_address] >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H [hostname] >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That will make sure there are no duplicate entries, that you are covered for both the hostname and IP address, and will also hash the output, an extra security measure.

Comment: Why do you need all 3 ssh-keyscan's? Can't you get by with just the first one since it works for both hostname and ip?

Comment: Can you be sure that the machine replying to the ssh-keyscan request is really the one you want to talk to? If not you've opened yourself to a man in the middle attack.

Comment: @JasperWallace Yes, for that you need at least the fingerprint or even better the public key, in which case you can add it directly to known_hosts, turning this question moot. If you only have the fingerprint, you will have to write an extra step which verifies the downloaded public key with your fingerprint...

Comment: Calls to `ssh-keyscan` were failing for me because my target host doesn't support the default version 1 key type. Adding `-t rsa,dsa` to the command fixed this.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. You are opening yourself to a man-in-the-middle attack by updating these keys.

To avoid duplicate entries, check the return status of `ssh-keygen -F [address]` instead.

https://medium.com/@wblankenship/bash-automatically-populating-a-known-hosts-file-15ea28d06c02

Comment: This is only slightly better than the accepted answer. If someone does a MITM attack on you when you do this, then you store their fake keys, and you permanently accept their MITM attack.

Comment: Make shure you use the right hostname else the key will not by valid

Comment: This is the right answer if you want to update a host.

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Comment: What I don't like about this answer is, that the command is not idempotent, i.e. if I accidentally run it twice or more times, I will clutter my `known_hosts` with duplicate entries, neither does it replace outdated entries for a host.

Comment: @con-f-use Since keys are removed first, the added, how would you get duplicates?

Answer (score 137):

For the lazy ones:

```
ssh-keyscan -H <host> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

-H hashes the hostname / IP address

Comment: "ssh-keyscan -H <host> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts" produces an entry more like what ssh does with user interaction. (The -H hashes the name of the remote host.)

Comment: Vulnerable to MITM attacks. You're not checking the key fingerprint.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo You say what to do but not how, which would be helpful.

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Comment: @jameshfisher Yes its vulnerable to MITM attacks, but have you ever compared the RSA fingerprint, which was shown to you with the actual one of the server, when you were doing this manually? No? So this answer is the way to do it for you. If yes, you shouldn't use this answer and do it manually or implement other security measures...

Comment: @Mnebuerquo I would be really glad if you also let us know a better way to handle this, when we need to clone a repo using batch scripts un-attended and we want to by-pass this prompt. Please shed some light on a real solution if you think this is not the right one!

Comment: @WaqasShah See the answer by BradChesney79 ... https://serverfault.com/a/807363/33170
This is a better way to do it. First verify the keys and fingerprints ahead of time, then upload them to your machine where you want to be able to do ssh connections. You can upload a complete known_hosts file first thing upon your script starting. If you're creating virtual machines, you can create the key when you create the image, so you know it before you start them up.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo Thanks for the link, it's such a coincidence that today I used this same approach and to me too this seems like the best one. Thanks anyways!

Comment: The answer by BradChesney79 is not in any sense a better way to do it. Literally all he is doing there is using nmap to get the SSH host key fingerprint and then comparing it to what ssh-keyscan says the fingerprint is. In both cases, the fingerprint comes from *the same place*. It's just as vulnerable to MITM as any other of these automated solutions. The *only* secure and valid way to verify an SSH public key is over some trusted out-of-band channel. (Or set up some kind of key-signing infrastructure.)

Comment: Key signing infrastructure +1

For out-of-band now-a-days, it often suffices to grab the fingerprint from your cloud dashboard (where you create your instances), which almost always have a direct console into the instance.  Add these to your list of trusted fingerprints. Then simply compare with the ssh-keyscan result. 

If you have physical access to the machine, even better!

Comment: Useful source: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-add-an-ssh-fingerprint-to-your-knownhosts-file-in-linux/; they recommend `ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.162 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, as does @SarahMesser

Answer (score 44):

As mentioned, using key-scan would be the right & unobtrusive way to do it.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa HOST 2>&1 | sort -u - ~/.ssh/known_hosts > ~/.ssh/tmp_hosts
mv ~/.ssh/tmp_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The above will do the trick to add a host, ONLY if it has not yet been added. It is also not concurrency safe; you *must not* execute the snippet on the same origin machine more than once at the same time, as the tmp_hosts file can get clobbered, ultimately leading to the known_hosts file becoming bloated...

Comment: Is there a way to check whether the key is in known_hosts **before** `ssh-keyscan`? The reason is that it requires some time and additional network connection.

Comment: The original poster's version of this file had `cat ~/.ssh/tmp_hosts > ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, but a subsequent edit changed it to `>>`. Using `>>` is an error. It defeats the purpose of the uniqueness in the first line, and causes it to dump new entries into `known_hosts` every time it runs. (Just posted an edit to change it back.)

Comment: This is subject to the same MITM attacks as the others.

Comment: @utapyngo ssh-keygen -F  will give you the current fingerprint. If it comes back blank with return code of 1, then you don't have it. If it prints something and return code is 0, then it's already present.

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Comment: If you care that much about MITM, deploy DNSSEC and SSHFP records or use some other secure means of distributing the keys and this kludge solution will be irrelevant.

Comment: Can HOSTS be a list of IP addresses, instead of only one?

Comment: Use `mktmp` or `tempfile` or similar to avoid the issue with clobbering a hard-coded temporary file.

Answer (score 20):

You could use `ssh-keyscan` command to grab the public key and append that to your `known_hosts` file.

Comment: Make sure you check the fingerprint to ensure it is the correct key. Otherwise you open yourself up to MITM attacks.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo Fair point in the general context, but why would someone be trying to programmatically gather keys if they already knew what the correct key was?

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Answer (score 13):

**Check the fingerprint** of each new server/host. This is the only way to authenticate the server. Without it, your SSH connection can be subject to a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

**Do not** use the old value `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` which *never* checks the authenticity of the server at all. Though the [meaning of  `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is planned to be flipped](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2400#c18) later.

Second option, but less secure, is to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new`, which was [introduced in version 7.6 (2017-10-03) of OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6):

> The first "accept-new" will automatically accept
> hitherto-unseen keys but will refuse connections for changed or
> invalid hostkeys.

Answer (score 11):

This is how you can incorporate **ssh-keyscan** into your play:

```
---
# ansible playbook that adds ssh fingerprints to known_hosts
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - command: /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan -T 10 {{ ansible_host }}
    register: keyscan
  - lineinfile: name=~/.ssh/known_hosts create=yes line={{ item }}
    with_items: '{{ keyscan.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}'
```

Comment: Are you uploading a known valid known_hosts file, or are you doing ssh-keyscan and dumping the output into known_hosts without verifying fingerprints?

Comment: This is simply dumps output of a keyscan, yes. So in effect it's the same as StrictHostKeyChecking=no, just with silent known_hosts updating without fiddling with ssh options. This solution also doesn't work well due to ssh-keyscan returning multiple lines which causes this task always be flagged as 'changed'

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Comment: @jameshfisher I would be really glad if you also let us know a better way to handle this, when we need to clone a repo using batch scripts un-attended and we want to by-pass this prompt. Please shed some light on a real solution if you think this is not the right one! Please let us know "how" to do it, if you think this is not the right way to do it!

Comment: It is a perfectly valid method of adding values to known_hosts, but yes it is susceptible to MITM. However, for internal use it is fine.

Comment: @WaqasShah Just validate against your repos' possible fingerprints.  For github they can be found here: https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/.  Now why is 'here' any more secure? Why PKI of course :)

Comment: @SyedWaqas As described in [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/820152/7408), you avoid the risk of MITM on the SSH channel by getting the public key generated by the VM during installation through a different channel.

Comment: @SyedWaqas Well you download the keys from the target servers, or if you dont have access from the api or website that allows it (like github), or lastly if no access whatsoever you can check from different endpoints (instances accross different continents)

Answer (score 10):

To do this properly, what you really want to do is collect the host public keys of the VMs as you create them and drop them into a file in `known_hosts` format. You can then use the `-o GlobalKnownHostsFile=...`, pointing to that file, to ensure that you're connecting to the host you believe you should be connecting to. How you do this depends on how you're setting up the virtual machines, however, but reading it off the virtual filesystem, if possible, or even getting the host to print the contents of `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` during configuration may do the trick.

That said, this may not be worthwhile, depending on what sort of environment you're working in and who your anticipated adversaries are. Doing a simple "store on first connect" (via a scan or simply during the first "real" connection) as described in several other answers above may be considerably easier and still provide some modicum of security. However, if you do this I strongly suggest you change the user known hosts file (`-o UserKnownHostsFile=...`) to a file specific
for this particular test installation; this will avoid polluting your personal known hosts file with test information and make it easy to clean up the now useless public keys when you delete your VMs.

Comment: Since those are VM's, you could have a way to access the filesystem and get those keys...

Answer (score 7):

This would be a complete solution, accepting host key for the first time only

```yaml
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
- name: accept ssh fingerprint automatically for the first time
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: "check if known_hosts contains server's fingerprint"
      command: ssh-keygen -F {{ inventory_hostname }}
      register: keygen
      failed_when: keygen.stderr != ''
      changed_when: False

    - name: fetch remote ssh key
      command: ssh-keyscan -T5 {{ inventory_hostname }}
      register: keyscan
      failed_when: keyscan.rc != 0 or keyscan.stdout == ''
      changed_when: False
      when: keygen.rc == 1

    - name: add ssh-key to local known_hosts
      lineinfile:
        name: ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        create: yes
        line: "{{ item }}"
      when: keygen.rc == 1
      with_items: '{{ keyscan.stdout_lines|default([]) }}'
```

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Comment: @jameshfisher Thanks for replying "MITM" to every answer on this thread. Do you have an actual solution? If not, please consider how your comments waste valuable screen space before hitting CTRL-V next time

Comment: @Dr-Bracket the top comment says it best, "The only valid way to make sure you're secure against MITM attacks is to verify the host's public key through some out-of-band trusted channel". In OP's example, they're "launching a number of virtual machine instances from a central client", which must provide such a trusted channel.

Answer (score 7):

I do a one-liner script, a bit long but useful to make this task for hosts with multiples IPs, using `dig` and `bash`

```
(host=github.com; ssh-keyscan -H $host; for ip in $(dig @8.8.8.8 github.com +short); do ssh-keyscan -H $host,$ip; ssh-keyscan -H $ip; done) 2> /dev/null >> .ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 6):

How are you building these machines? can you run a dns update script? can you join an IPA Domain?

FreeIPA does this automatically, but essentially all you need is [SSHFP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4255.txt) dns records and [DNSSEC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4033.txt) on your zone (freeipa provides as configurable options (dnssec disabled by default)).

You can get the existing SSHFP records from your host by running.

`ssh-keygen -r jersey.jacobdevans.com`

> jersey.jacobdevans.com IN SSHFP 1 1 4d8589de6b1a48e148d8fc9fbb967f1b29f53ebc jersey.jacobdevans.com IN SSHFP 1 2 6503272a11ba6d7fec2518c02dfed88f3d455ac7786ee5dbd72df63307209d55
>   jersey.jacobdevans.com IN SSHFP 3 1 5a7a1e8ab8f25b86b63c377b303659289b895736 > jersey.jacobdevans.com IN SSHFP 3 2 1f50f790117dfedd329dbcf622a7d47551e12ff5913902c66a7da28e47de4f4b

then once published, you'd add `VerifyHostKeyDNS yes` to your ssh_config or ~/.ssh/config

If/When google decides to flip on DNSSEC, you could ssh in without a hostkey prompt.

`ssh jersey.jacobdevans.com`

BUT my domain is not signed yet, so for now you'd see....

> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:H1D3kBF9/t0ynbz2IqfUdVHhL/WROQLGan2ijkfeT0s
>
> debug1: found 4 insecure fingerprints in DNS
>
> debug1: matching host key fingerprint
>
> found in DNS The authenticity of host 'jersey.jacobdevans.com (2605:6400:10:434::10)' can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is
>    SHA256:H1D3kBF9/t0ynbz2IqfUdVHhL/WROQLGan2ijkfeT0s. Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and found that some of the provided answers only got me part way to an automated solution. The following is what I ended up using, hope it helps:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o PasswordAuthentication=no 10.x.x.x
```

It adds the key to `known_hosts` and doesn't prompt for the password.

Comment: Vulnerable to MITM attacks. You're not checking the fingerprint.

Comment: Nobody checks the fingerprint.

Answer (score 5):

The following avoid duplicate entries in ~/.ssh/known_hosts:

```bash
if ! grep "$(ssh-keyscan github.com 2>/dev/null)" ~/.ssh/known_hosts > /dev/null; then
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
fi
```

Comment: This is not the way to do it. MITM.

Comment: I like this answer best. For scripting initial setup of a random VPS of no importance to anyone but me, MITM risk is vanishingly small.    Infinitesimal quibble ... first line needs to be `mkdir -p ~/.ssh/known_hosts;`

Comment: Aside from security concerns mentioned elsewhere, this *will* generate duplicates, as a new hash is generated every time

Comment: `if ! ssh-keygen -F github.com > /dev/null; then ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts; fi`

Answer (score 4):

This whole

- ssh-key-scan
- ssh-copy-id
- ECSDA key warning

business kept annoying me so I opted for

**One script to rule them all**

This is a variant of the script at https://askubuntu.com/a/949731/129227 with Amadu Bah's answer https://serverfault.com/a/858957/162693 in a loop.

**example call**

./sshcheck somedomain site1 site2 site3

The script will loop over the names sites and modify the .ssh/config and .ssh/known_hosts file and do ssh-copy-id on request - for the last feature just the let the ssh test calls fail e.g. by hitting enter 3 times on the password request.

**sshcheck script**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2017-08-25
# check ssh access to bitplan servers

#ansi colors
#http://www.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html
blue='\033[0;34m'  
red='\033[0;31m'  
green='\033[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white bg.
endColor='\033[0m'

#
# a colored message 
#   params:
#     1: l_color - the color of the message
#     2: l_msg - the message to display
#
color_msg() {
  local l_color="$1"
  local l_msg="$2"
  echo -e "${l_color}$l_msg${endColor}"
}

#
# error
#
#   show an error message and exit
#
#   params:
#     1: l_msg - the message to display
error() {
  local l_msg="$1"
  # use ansi red for error
  color_msg $red "Error: $l_msg" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

#
# show the usage
#
usage() {
  echo "usage: $0 domain sites"
  exit 1 
}

#
# check known_hosts entry for server
#
checkknown() {
  local l_server="$1"
  #echo $l_server
  local l_sid="$(ssh-keyscan $l_server 2>/dev/null)" 
  #echo $l_sid
  if (! grep "$l_sid" $sknown) > /dev/null 
  then
    color_msg $blue "adding $l_server to $sknown"
    ssh-keyscan $l_server >> $sknown 2>&1
  fi
}

#
# check the given server
#
checkserver() {
  local l_server="$1"
  grep $l_server $sconfig > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 1 ]
  then
    color_msg $blue "adding $l_server to $sconfig"
    today=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
    echo "# added $today by $0"  >> $sconfig
    echo "Host $l_server" >> $sconfig
    echo "   StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> $sconfig
    echo "   userKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" >> $sconfig
    echo "" >> $sconfig
    checkknown $l_server
  else
    color_msg $green "$l_server found in $sconfig"
  fi
  ssh -q $l_server id > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    color_msg $green "$l_server accessible via ssh"
  else
    color_msg $red "ssh to $l_server failed" 
    color_msg $blue "shall I ssh-copy-id credentials to $l_server?"
    read answer
    case $answer in
      y|yes) ssh-copy-id $l_server
    esac
  fi
}

#
# check all servers
#
checkservers() {
me=$(hostname -f)
for server in $(echo $* | sort)
do
  os=`uname`
  case $os in
   # Mac OS X
   Darwin*)
     pingoption=" -t1";;
    *) ;;
  esac

  pingresult=$(ping $pingoption -i0.2 -c1 $server)
  echo $pingresult | grep 100 > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 1 ]
  then 
    checkserver $server
    checkserver $server.$domain
  else
    color_msg $red "ping to $server failed"
  fi
done
}

#
# check configuration
#
checkconfig() {
#https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh
  if [ -f $sconfig ]
  then
    color_msg $green "$sconfig exists"
    ls -l $sconfig
  fi
}

sconfig=~/.ssh/config
sknown=~/.ssh/known_hosts

case  $# in
  0) usage ;;
  1) usage ;;
  *) 
    domain=$1 
    shift 
    color_msg $blue "checking ssh configuration for domain $domain sites $*"
    checkconfig
    checkservers $* 
    #for server in $(echo $* | sort)
    ##do
    #  checkknown $server 
    #done
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to check the key before adding it blindly, you can use this code:

```sh
# verify github and gitlab key
# GitHub
github=SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
ssh-keyscan github.com >> githubKey
read bit githubkey host <<< $(ssh-keygen -lf githubKey)
if [ "$githubkey" != "$github" ]
then
  echo "The GitHub fingerprint is incorrect"
  exit 1
fi
echo "github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts

# GitLab
gitlab=SHA256:ROQFvPThGrW4RuWLoL9tq9I9zJ42fK4XywyRtbOz/EQ
ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> gitlabKey
read bit gitlabkey host <<< $(ssh-keygen -lf gitlabKey)
if [ "$githubkey" != "$github" ]
then
  echo "The GitLab fingerprint is incorrect"
  exit 1
fi
echo "gitlab.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsj2bNKTBSpIYDEGk9KxsGh3mySTRgMtXL583qmBpzeQ+jqCMRgBqB98u3z++J1sKlXHWfM9dyhSevkMwSbhoR8XIq/U0tCNyokEi/ueaBMCvbcTHhO7FcwzY92WK4Yt0aGROY5qX2UKSeOvuP4D6TPqKF1onrSzH9bx9XUf2lEdWT/ia1NEKjunUqu1xOB/StKDHMoX4/OKyIzuS0q/T1zOATthvasJFoPrAjkohTyaDUz2LN5JoH839hViyEG82yB+MjcFV5MU3N1l1QL3cVUCh93xSaua1N85qivl+siMkPGbO5xR/En4iEY6K2XPASUEMaieWVNTRCtJ4S8H+9" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

The GitHub and GitLab keys may change if they get compromised. In this case, check the most recent ones [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html) and [there](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints)

**Remark**: You may need to ensure that the key is not added twice. For this, refer to other answers.

Answer (score 3):

So, I was searching for a mundane way to bypass the unkown host manual interaction of cloning a git repo as shown below:

```
brad@computer:~$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:viperks/viperks-api.git
Cloning into 'viperks-api'...
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (104.192.143.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Note the RSA key fingerprint...

So, this is a SSH thing, this will work for git over SSH and just SSH related things in general...

```
brad@computer:~$ nmap bitbucket.org --script ssh-hostkey

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-05 10:21 EDT
Nmap scan report for bitbucket.org (104.192.143.3)
Host is up (0.032s latency).
Other addresses for bitbucket.org (not scanned): 104.192.143.2 104.192.143.1 2401:1d80:1010::150
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
| ssh-hostkey:
|   1024 35:ee:d7:b8:ef:d7:79:e2:c6:43:9e:ab:40:6f:50:74 (DSA)
|_  2048 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40 (RSA)
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 42.42 seconds
```

First, install nmap on your daily driver. nmap is highly helpful for certain things, like detecting open ports and this-- manually verifying SSH fingerprints. But, back to what we are doing.

Good. I'm either compromised at the multiple places and machines I've checked it-- or the more plausible explanation of everything being hunky dory is what is happening.

That 'fingerprint' is just a string shortened with a one way algorithm for our human convenience at the risk of more than one string resolving into the same fingerprint. It happens, they are called collisions.

Regardless, back to the original string which we can see in context below.

```
brad@computer:~$ ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org
# bitbucket.org SSH-2.0-conker_1.0.257-ce87fba app-128
no hostkey alg
# bitbucket.org SSH-2.0-conker_1.0.257-ce87fba app-129
bitbucket.org ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw==
# bitbucket.org SSH-2.0-conker_1.0.257-ce87fba app-123
no hostkey alg
```

So, ahead of time, we have a way of asking for a form of identification from the original host.

At this point we manually are as vulnerable as automatically-- the strings match, we have the base data that creates the fingerprint, and we could ask for that base data (preventing collisions) in the future.

Now to use that string in a way that prevents asking about a hosts authenticity...

The known_hosts file in this case does not use plaintext entries. You'll know hashed entries when you see them, they look like hashes with random characters instead of xyz.com or 123.45.67.89.

```
brad@computer:~$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa -H bitbucket.org
# bitbucket.org SSH-2.0-conker_1.0.257-ce87fba app-128
|1|yr6p7i8doyLhDtrrnWDk7m9QVXk=|LuKNg9gypeDhfRo/AvLTAlxnyQw= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw==
```

The first comment line infuriatingly shows up-- but you can get rid of it with a simple redirect via the ">" or ">>" convention.

As I've done my best to obtain untainted data to be used to identify a "host" and trust, I will add this identification to my known_hosts file in my ~/.ssh directory. Since it will now be identified as a known host, I will not get the prompt mentioned above when you were a youngster.

Thanks for sticking with me, here you go. I'm adding the bitbucket RSA key so that I can interact with my git repositories there in a non-interactive way as part of a CI workflow, but whatever you do what you want.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cp ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts.old && echo "|1|yr6p7i8doyLhDtrrnWDk7m9QVXk=|LuKNg9gypeDhfRo/AvLTAlxnyQw= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw==" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

So, that's how you stay a virgin for today. You can do the same with github by following similar directions on your own time.

I saw so many stack overflow posts telling you to programmatically add the key blindly without any kind of checking. The more you check the key from different machines on different networks, the more trust you can have that the host is the one it says it is-- and that is the best you can hope from this layer of security.

WRONG
<del>ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname [command]</del>

WRONG
<del>ssh-keyscan -t rsa -H hostname >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts</del>

Don't do either of the above things, please. You're given the opportunity to increase your chances of avoiding someone eavesdropping on your data transfers via a man in the middle attack-- take that opportunity. The difference is literally verifying that the RSA key you have is the one of the bona fide server and now you know how to get that information to compare them so you can trust the connection. Just remember more comparisons from different computers & networks will usually increase your ability to trust the connection.

Comment: I think this is the best solution to this problem. However, be very careful while using Nmap on something like Amazon EC2, I got a warning about the port scanning that Nmap does! Fill in their form before doing portscanning!

Comment: ...well, yeah. I don't know why you would do the port scanning from EC2. If you are logged in to your account, you can just get the keys from the actual machines.

This is more for machines you don't have control over. I would assume you would have a local machine not subject to AWS port scanning restrictions to use.

But, if you are in that edge case situation where you must run nmap with AWS, I suppose this warning would be helpful.

Comment: Using nmap to read the SSH host key from your workstation and then trusting that value is no different than connecting via SSH with StructHostKeyChecking turned off. Its just as vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: ...@MicahRLedbetter which is why I suggested that "more comparisons from different computers & networks will usually increase your ability to trust the connection".

But, that is my point. If you only ever check your target host from one set of environment conditions then how would you ever know of any discrepancies?

Did you have any better suggestions?

Comment: This is security theater. Doing something complicated to create the appearance of greater security. It doesn't matter how many different methods you use to ask the host for its key. Like asking the same person multiple times if you can trust them (maybe you call, email, text, and snail mail) . They'll always say yes, but if you're asking the wrong person, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman, from the same computer on the same network or even a different computer on the same network-- yes, it would be a waste of time. Different machine on a completely separate network-- no. If you achieve the same results from asking via different paths with isolated risks of a compromised request and tainted connection, you can increase the confidence your connection to the remote resource has not been unusually tampered with. In most cases, overkill. Just depends on the minimum security requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do a collection of hosts

define a collection of hosts

```
ssh_hosts:
  - server1.domain.com
  - server2.domain.com
  - server3.domain.com
  - server4.domain.com
  - server5.domain.com
  - server6.domain.com
  - server7.domain.com
  - server8.domain.com
  - server9.domain.com
```

Then define two tasks to add the keys to known hosts:

```
- command: "ssh-keyscan {{item}}"
   register: known_host_keys
   with_items: "{{ssh_hosts}}"
   tags:
     - "ssh"

 - name: Add ssh keys to know hosts
   known_hosts:
     name: "{{item.item}}"
     key: "{{item.stdout}}"
     path: ~/.ssh/known_hosts
   with_items: "{{known_host_keys.results}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `.pub` then anyone telling you about `ssh-keyscan` is asking you to risk a MitM attack.

> I'm setting up a test harness that will, from a central client, launch a number of virtual machine instances and then execute commands on them via ssh.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34908270/1111557) from StackOverflow has a better more correct answer. You must obtain the `.pub` file from a trusted source -- your system bootstrapper should call home and provide the file to a management system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: "${pubkey=-"$2"}"
: "${host=-"$1"}"

TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS=$(mktemp)
echo "${host}" "$(cat "${pubkey}")" > "${TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS}"

ssh-keygen -H -f "${TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS}"
ssh-keygen -F "${host}" -f "${TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS}" | tee ~/.ssh/known_hosts

shred "${TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS}.old"
rm -f "${TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS}" "${TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS}.old"
```

You can try this with your local host keys:

`$ for pubkey in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*.pub; do ./add_pubkey localhost "${pubkey}"; done`

Answer (score 1):

To automatically accept and memorize the fingerprint on never-before-seen remote git server, e.g. when executing `git clone git@example.com`, you can leverage *git*'s `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` together with *ssh*'s `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new`:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new" git clone git@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of SSH support certificate authorities, much like the ones used for SSL/TLS which secure your everyday web browsing. This allows you to bypass the Trust On First Use mechanism, as trust is already established by the CA. This works for both users (authorized keys) and hosts (known hosts).

Note this will complicate the process by which you bring up the VMs, as you will need all systems configured to trust the CA, and will need to have your CA sign the host keys for the VMs before you can use it to skip TOFU.

Here are some links to documentation about it:

https://www.lorier.net/docs/ssh-ca.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-creating_ssh_ca_certificate_signing-keys

https://jameshfisher.com/2018/03/16/how-to-create-an-ssh-certificate-authority/

https://smallstep.com/blog/use-ssh-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

Since those are "VM's", you should be able to go into them by other means (ex: mount the filesystem), and get the keys.

Once you get the public key's, you could build up your "known_hosts" (concatenate public keys).

Or the other way back: push a known private key on each slave by accessing the filesystem of the VM's.

This solution is overkill for simple cases where you master your environment, but it is not sensible to "men-in-the-middle" attack...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ! ssh-keygen -F HOST; then
    ssh-keyscan HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
fi
```

or in case of a custom port:

```
if ! ssh-keygen -F [HOST]:PORT; then
    ssh-keyscan -p PORT HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
fi
```

But this is vulnerable to MITM.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a rare case but I needed to connect 2 `docker` containers using SSH recently. First I made it work [using `ssh-keyscan`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/21f2553004e7124cff1df59fc6cba878):

```sh
/usr/sbin/sshd
wait4ports tcp://"$1":22
if ! ssh-keygen -F "$1"; then
    ssh-keyscan "$1" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
fi
```

Then, [w/o `ssh-keyscan`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/624e431e00ffa86efbf07e86d9efadbe) (by pregenerating the keys and injecting them from the host):

```sh
awk -v "host=$1" '{print host, $1, $2}' \
    /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub \
    /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub \
    /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub \
    > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

The host keys can be generated this way (well, there might be an easier way):

```sh
docker run --rm alpine:3.15 sh -euc '
    (apk add openssh
    ssh-keygen -A
    cd /etc/ssh
    tar czf keys.tar.gz ssh_host*) >/dev/null
    cat ~/.ssh/keys.tar.gz
' > keys.tar.gz
tar xf keys.tar.gz
rm keys.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone complaining about MITM issues:

First off, if you are afraid of MITM attacks rethink your infrastructure deployment and network design.

But if you have no choice. This might be a viable solution:

**On the host running SSHD, do:**

ssh-keygen -l -v -E sha256 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub

**On your SSH client host, do:**

ssh -o visualhostkey=yes -o FingerprintHash=sha256 myuser@my.ssh.server

Now compare the pictures, are they similar? Congratulations type "yes" on your client host to automatically add to known_hosts.
Are they different? Might be a MITM attack, or you just might be sloppy.
This is an OK solution if you just have password access. [Let's hope nobody has your password](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords).

**But let's dig deeper and analyze the real problem here:**

The problem really is a physical rather than a technical. Ask yourself, what is the first network layer? Think about it.

Some viable solutions to that are:

If you are in the the same physical location. Grab a new router, a switch and create a local-network that is not connected to the internet or any other unknown network.
Here you can use StrictHostKeyChecking=no as much as you please no MITM worries.
Same goes for Virtual Machines that you run directly on your workstation in an isolated network. Don't need to worry about MITM attacks if you control the physical network layer.

Consider buying a KVM-switch, use HPE iLO, IPMI or even Pi-KVM if your server supports it. But even then, these services should be on an isolated network as well. You can also use Intel-ME on laptops or workstations, but that is a whole other can of worms.

Copy your servers key fingerprint to an USB-stick, go back to your client and add the fingerprint manually to known_hosts from the USB-stick. It's elaborate, but you will be able to sleep at night. You can even automate this somewhat with a script.
If you want to be über-clever and impress the arrogant minion above you, automate this with "Rubber Ducky" or alike. But don't be clever. Someones "cleverness" brought us here in the first place.

Consider adding keys during the installation of your clients.
For example on Debian you can use Preseed and a custom ISO. There are many many solutions here.

If you don't have access to the servers location. Call a trusted friend over the phone and ask him to verify the fingerprint before you add it to known_hosts. But often if you don't have physical access, you are probably working for a company that already has secure solutions for this kind of situation. If not, consider changing jobs, or be a smarty and offer your boss a better solution in exchange for a raise. (remember to mention the word "Ransomware" at least 5 times during that conversation).

If all of the above is not an option for you. And you desperately want to connect to an unknown machine somewhere on the internet while using an unencrypted proxy chain. You should reconsider your life choices. Or you might just be the man in the middle.

Comment: I'd add ten minuses to this dissertation if I could.

Answer (score -1):

I had faced a similar issue where despite using the above mentioned verified solution, my ssh was not working and it was because the known_hosts file was missing from ~/.ssh/ directory and the File System was read only. SO during run time also I was unable to create the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.

If you face the similar issue then see if you can write the known_hosts file in the /tmp location. This is mostly write enabled even in a read-only file system.

Later in the ssh command you can specify the ssh to read the known_hosts file from /tmp location.

**ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user_name@destination_server_ip**

Comment: Your answer does not include a solution to the question: `Can I automatically add a new host to known_hosts?`

Comment: Hi @inetknght, request you to please read the last line I have mentioned in my answer to this problem statement. I have addressed 2 issues here:
1. When the known_hosts file itself is missing from the system and the system is read-only.
2. automatically add a new host to known_hosts

Please let me know in case you need more clarity here.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to add the host to ~/.ssh/known-hosts (and dont add duplicated ones) as guided [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1090385/41015)

e.g. adding `gitlab.com`

```
ssh-keygen -F gitlab.com || ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's my edge case:

I'm creating a fabric 2.5 script to deploy a website on a new site. At one point, it will create a ssh key, and add the public key to gitlab using it's api. Then, it will clone a repo (containing the website source code).
The clone command failed in the script, and when I went on the server and manually launched the command I had the `The authenticity of host 'host.com ()' can't be established. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` prompt.

At first my solution was to search how to auto-accept it, but for security concern I added the `pty=True` arg in the `c.run("command")` function, and I was given access to the error during the execution of my script.

Comment: Your answer does not include a solution to the question: `Can I automatically add a new host to known_hosts?`

Comment: It includes a solution to the question `The problem [...] is that the first ssh command run against a new virtual instance always comes up with an interactive prompt [...]. Is there a way that I can bypass this [...] ?`. I found this question by typing `interactive prompt fabric` and thought that maybe other people will stumble across this for the same reasons.