# sshd is not honoring sshd_config settings

Tags: networking, centos, ssh, docker, centos7

I am adding the following settings to my docker based centos 7 `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
Match User ansible
        PermitEmptyPasswords yes
        PasswordAuthentication no
        PermitRootLogin without-password
        PubkeyAuthentication no
        HostbasedAuthentication yes
```

And I am noticing that sshd is not honoring those settings, at least it is still asking for a password. In  my set up, my `ansible` user does not have a password at all, but I still require it to shell into various machines without authentication. I do know about `ssh-copy-id` however since this is a closed docker network, I am wanting to bypass they key handling and just allow the user `ansible` to pass in.

I know it's not secure, however this is just for a test environment for development only.

What additional settings should I add to my sshd_config file to ensure I am never bothered for a password nor asked to type in "yes" to accept a fingerprint?

Here is what I see when inside my docker:

```
[root@docker-ansible /]# ssh ansible@portal.docker.local

The authenticity of host 'portal.docker.local (172.31.0.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:klErLlMAooQXDpAVNAsGoQTt5r+GdjDX06Fgihstteo.
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:60:4e:1e:6a:05:12:45:e9:21:79:4b:22:0b:1b:a7:cd.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes <-- I need to not be typing yes here.

Warning: Permanently added 'portal.docker.local,172.31.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,hostbased).
```

When I try again, after typing in "yes", still:

```
[root@docker-ansible /]# ssh ansible@portal.docker.local

Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,hostbased).
```

Update:
I just tried @telcoM's idea and although this feels close, it doesn't work. The end of my `sshd_config` file is this:

```
Match User ansible 
   PermitEmptyPasswords yes 
   AuthenticationMethods none
```

But now the error i get is:

```
[ansible@docker-ansible ~]$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no portal.docker.local
ansible@ocker-ansible's password:
:(
```

So it appears to be wanting the password still...

Comment: Your separate second question about the ssh host key is [answered here](https://serverfault.com/q/132970/126632).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The host key fingerprints and the "Are you sure you want to continue connecting?" prompt is generated by *your SSH client*, not the remote `sshd`. No amount of configuration on the `sshd` server will change that. The setting you need to change in either your local personal `~/.ssh/config` or in local system-wide `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is `StrictHostKeyChecking`.

- If you set it to `accept-new`, new keys will be accepted, but changed keys on previously-known hosts will not be.
- If you set it to `no`, both new and changed host keys will be accepted.
- The default setting is `ask`, which is what you currently have.
- Setting it to `yes` is the most strict option: with this setting, the SSH client will never connect unless it has the host key available locally in advance (maximum security, minimum convenience).

Now let's analyze your `sshd_config` snippet:

```
Match User ansible
        PermitEmptyPasswords yes
        PasswordAuthentication no
        PermitRootLogin without-password
        PubkeyAuthentication no
        HostbasedAuthentication yes
```

- `PermitEmptyPasswords yes`: not very applicable as you have set `PasswordAuthentication no`. This may still prevent `sshd` from treating a passwordless user account as equivalent to a disabled one.
- `PasswordAuthentication no`: you'll never get asked for a password for this user (or if you do, it will be a fake prompt just to waste the time of a potential intruder)
- `PermitRootLogin without-password`: no effect here, we're within a `Match User ansible` block, we're talking about logging in as user `ansible`, not as `root`.
- `PubkeyAuthentication no`: `~ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys` will have no effect.
- `HostbasedAuthentication yes`: this one may not work the way you think it does.

### Requirements for HostbasedAuthentication

In order for `HostbasedAuthentication` to allow your login, the host key of the host you're coming from must already exist in the remote `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` or in `~ansible/.ssh/known_hosts`, **and either** your local hostname must be listed in system-wide `/etc/ssh/shosts.equiv` or `/etc/hosts.equiv` **or** your local hostname and username must be listed in `~ansible/.shosts` or `~ansible/.rhosts`.

So `HostbasedAuthentication` is definitely not the no-preparation get-in-without-password setup you may have imagined it to be.

To get a fully wide-open, no-authentication set-up for the `ansible` user, try this Match block:

```
Match User ansible
    PermitEmptyPasswords yes
    AuthenticationMethods none
```

**Obviously, NEVER use this on anything that is connected to the internet.**

Comment: Tried this but doesn't work. I updated the bottom of my question with my latest try

Comment: I'm not sure if this changes things, but that `ansible` account is never given a password in the first place

Comment: @E.S. It does. If you just create an user account without setting a password on it, you don't get an account with a blank password - you get an account that *hasn't been enabled yet.* To enable an account with a blank password, you need to do it explicitly using `usermod -p "" ansible` or similar.