# How safely obtain and check host public key for `known_hosts`?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

For a newly deployed instance I get the following message for the first time SSH connection:

```
The authenticity of host '[hostname] ([IP address])' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is [key fingerprint].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I want to avoid this interaction with the user.

How to safely obtain, check and save this public key?

Comment: Use DNSSEC and store keys in SSHFP records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I automatically add a new host to known\_hosts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts)

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: `That leaves you open to man in the middle attacks, probably not a good idea.`

Comment: No, SSHFP with DNSSEC does not lead to MitM.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov So I'm in an environment where all DNS lookups and all outgoing connections. I cannot ensure that my DNS resolvers will validate DNSSEC-signed domains. How can I confirm that my key returns are secure?

Comment: Either distribute statically (via side channel — you have to do all the automation yourself, like write script which verifies ssh-keyscan output via HTTPS or whatever you trust and have user to run it appropriately) or with DNSSEC. No other options. No DNSSEC, no easy and convenient way.